# Can I use parseInt with session Storage?

Tags: javascript, parseint, session-storage

I'd like to use `sessionStorage` in my program, but I need the variable stored as an integer. Is it possible to use `parseInt()` for that? Like:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("j",0);
var j = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("j"));
```

Comment: have you tried running this code?

Comment: ehm, no.. Because i've alredy a program that uses cookies, but i got stuck! Now first of implementing session storage i'd like to be sure that it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can, but your code as written needs to change `localStorage` to `sessionStorage`.  Something like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("j",0);
var j = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("j"));
console.log(j)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes my bad, i wrote it wrong :P What does the console.log(j) do?

Comment: If you press F12 in your browser, it will show you the developer console.  `console.log()` is used to print messages to the console, it helps with debugging.  There's more info on it here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: No i don't. If i'm here there is a reason.

Comment: Thank you very much! At least someone is kind today

Comment: @FrancescoMonti : I had a similar question  (how to "store" an int value in sessionStorage) and your question and especially the answer gave me the solution. Therefore a "kind" upvote to your question and also the answer ;-)